# Stop Chrome from downloading a certain file

Tags: google-chrome, download

I use LogMeIn to remote into my clients via Chrome browser.
The recent update from LMI asks me to download a file, for creating session.
How can i stop chrome from downloading this file?
I'm tired of cancelling this again and again...
the file name is always the same "LogMeIn Client.exe"

Any idea on this please?
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can reroute your address to LogMeIn to go past the page (where it wants you to download). For example, instead of going through wikipedia''s main page, you can just shoot straight to the url (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stackflow).

Sorry if this isn't what you were looking for.  I don't think chrome has anything implemented to combat this.  You can always change firewall settings to auto block but I feel this would cause, maybe, a few more popups.